# Android BroadcstReciever

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I am using a broadcast receiver. I am new to android, so I am not sure how to add the receiver in the manifest file. My code:

```
<receiver android:name="Reciever" />
```

`Reciever` is the name of a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. When the user clicks on button then after 5 seconds I want to call this Receiver. So I have written this:

```
AlarmManager am= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Here "sender" is pending intent.
But it's not working, please suggest to me?

Comment: Try this [custom-intents-and-broadcasting](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: Yes i have used but it's giving me Exception of "request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
"

Comment: refer this link ... may help you http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/generate-qr-code-using-google-chart-api.html

Comment: Then there is a problem with your Socket Connection Not With this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android:name should point to the receiver class e.g 'com.foo.TestReceiver' or just '.TestReceiver' because you might have stated the package name earlier. Also, just having a receiver doesn't make much sense. You need an  tag inside the receiver to specify the trigger when your receiver runs.
Take a look at the code samples provided at the developer site for more.

Answer (score 0):

U missed a . in Front of the Receiver name.

It should be

```
<receiver android:name=".Reciever"></receiver>
```